# Any way to fix a stuck pixel in an LCD screen?

Tags: lcd, dead-pixel

I have an older LCD monitor, and it has recently developed a single green pixel that's always on.  It's not really annoying if the screen is bright, but it's very noticeable when there's something dark on the screen.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: did any of this help with fixing that pixel?

Comment: I ran jScreenFix and it seems to have fixed one pixel, but there's still another one lit - but it is a lot less noticeable now.  I was actually surprised that it did anything.

Comment: dup: http://superuser.com/questions/38231/what-is-the-best-way-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-a-lcd-screen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**JScreenFix**](http://www.jscreenfix.com/basic.php) might be worth a try.

Some references that discuss on pixel problems.

- WikiHOW -- [**How to Fix a Stuck Pixel on an LCD Monitor**](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Stuck-Pixel-on-an-LCD-Monitor)
- MakeUseOf -- [**5 Ways To Fix A Stuck Pixel On Your Screen**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-software-solutions-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-your-lcd-monitor/)
- [**HOW TO: Fix a stuck pixel on an LCD screen**](http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2007/08/06/how-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-an-lcd-screen/)

Comment: same links as mine.. ;)

Comment: +1, useful resources. While not all stuck/dead pixels can be fixed, these are certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 7):

Your dead pixel might actually be a [stuck pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel).

> **Wikipedia:** Stuck pixels, unlike dead pixels, have been reported by LCD screen owners to disappear, and there are several popular methods purported to fix them,[9] such as gently rubbing the screen (in an attempt to reset the pixel), cycling the color value of the stuck pixel rapidly (in other words, flashing bright colors on the screen,) or simply tolerating the stuck pixel until it disappears (which can take anywhere from a day to years). While these methods can work on some stuck pixels others cannot be fixed by the above methods. Also some stuck pixels will reappear after being fixed if the screen is left off for several hours.

Either way, it seems like there are several possible techniques you could try to fix this.

- Pressure method
- Tapping method
- Heat method

[This howto](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Stuck-Pixel-on-an-LCD-Monitor) shows these techniques step by step and has a good explanation of the process. Hope one of these techniques can help out

There are several several [software-tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-software-solutions-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-your-lcd-monitor/) you could use to remedy this as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to re-seat the edge connector to the LCD display if you dare take it apart.  The prognosis is not good however.  In many cases there is no way to fix this kind of a problem, but sometimes you get lucky.  So don't be afraid to try if you are comfortable with this level of complicated dis-assembly and re-assembly.

Comment: roll the disclaimer... ;)

Comment: That might affect a whole row or column on some simple LCD panels that aren't multiplexed, but I seriously doubt you can do anything at all about a single dead pixel on any LCD or multiple ones on those with a higher-level interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've read if you "knead" the pixel when you turn on the monitor, sometimes its wake up the pixel.. But i have two dead pix on my screen and a lot of massages after... They are still dead...

Comment: i've heard this too, but i believe this just has to be tried out